# I having trouble getting Layout Builder Styles Module to work correctly

Tags: theming, 9, layout-builder

I'm trying to use Layout Builder Styles on Drupal 9 to style my blocks and sections in layout builder. The problem is none of the styling is being applied to the displayed content.

This is the guidance provided by the documentation regarding the field where you enter your styles.
"A list of CSS classes to apply to the block wrapper. Please note that no class selector is needed."

If no class selector is needed then what syntax do I use:

{
left: 40px;
top: 40px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
z-index: 1;
}

Do I kill the brackets and just list the properties?

Tim

Comment: *A "style" is just a representation of one or more CSS classes that will be applied.* --> I don't know the module, but seemingly you need to add CSS class names there, not styles. You also need to add the styles for those classes in your custom theme.

Comment: It also says that no class selector is needed. That is why I am confused. The first thing I tried was a full class declaration.

Comment: The dot is the class selector

Comment: This is what I have in there now:

post_category {
left: 40px;
top: 40px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
z-index: 1;
}

No result